# PHP to C# Exchange Currency Rates

Tags: c#, php

Hi I am trying to get exchange rates data from the below website into my C# application. If you scroll down in the below link there is a developers section and code is in PHP. I don't really know if this can be implemented in C# as I am new to PHP.

Any help on different ways to implement this or how to make this PHP code works in my C# application. It is very important to use this website as this is the official euro foreign exchange rates.

http://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/exchange/eurofxref/html/index.en.html

How can I extract data and manage this data from my C# applications

```
<gesmes:Envelope xmlns:gesmes="http://www.gesmes.org/xml/2002-08-01" xmlns="http://www.ecb.int/vocabulary/2002-08-01/eurofxref">
<gesmes:subject>Reference rates</gesmes:subject>
<gesmes:Sender>
<gesmes:name>European Central Bank</gesmes:name>
</gesmes:Sender>
<Cube>
<Cube time="2016-07-05">
<Cube currency="USD" rate="1.1146"/>
<Cube currency="JPY" rate="113.50"/>
</Cube>
</Cube>
</gesmes:Envelope>
```

Comment: We are not a free code conversion service.

Comment: As @Epodax noted, Stack Overflow is to help solve specific problems, not open-ended ones like this. See the "What topics can I ask about here?" page (http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) where it reads questions "must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just Quick and Dirty :

```
using (var webClient = new WebClient())
{
  var xml = webClient.DownloadString("http://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml");
  var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
  xmlDoc.LoadXml(xml);
  foreach (XmlElement child in xmlDoc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes[2].ChildNodes[0])
  {
    var currency = child.Attributes[0].InnerText;
    var rate = child.Attributes[1].InnerText;
    Console.WriteLine("1€={0} {1}", rate, currency);
  }
}
```